# Difference between val.length and val().length in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is difference between `$("#id").val.length` and `$("#id").val().length`?

When I write `$("#id").val.length` then the output is `1` and `$("#id").val().length` then the output is the length of the written characters.

What is the explanation?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length: It's just `($.fn.val).length`

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when the question has absolutely nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`$("#id").val` returns the function definition of `val` and [**`length` of a function is the number of parameters the function is expecting**](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-instances-length) as the `val` takes one parameter(**setter** to set the value) the length is 1, whereas `val()` will invoke the function and get the returned value and `length` on it will return the number of characters in the value.

The correct use is `$(selector).val().length`

I will also recommend to use VanillaJS's [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) or jQuery's [$.trim](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) on `val()` before checking `length` to remove leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: `length of a function is the number of parameters the function is expecting` Very nice! Did not know that. (and yes, have tested it). Try `(function test(one, two){}).length`

Answer (score 9):

Let us have a look at both the code:

**Case 1:**

```
$("#id").val.length
```

Here .val return the method definition for `.val()`. and .length  along with it returns number of maximum argument methods accepts(for example 2 for `.toggleClass()`)

**Case 2:**

```
$("#id").val().length
```

Here `.val()` returns the method evaluation result i.e. value of DOM object in string format and .length returns the length string value returned.

**Correct way:**

Case 2 is the correct way of using `.val()` along with length as it returns length of value of element associated to it.

Comment: `As count of number of method is 1, .length along with it returns 1.` this isn't correct. The count of the *number of parameters* of the method is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

With `$("#id").val` you get the function (the source code) and with `$("#id").val()` this function will be called and executed.